# How to connect to shared external drives on win11 machine

Tags: networking, hard-drive, samba

I have checked the referenced previous questions, but none seem to be my issue.  I am using release 22.04, jammy-jellyfish.

I have a win11 machine with 8 external hard drives and 2 internal hard drives.  I am attempting to somehow be able to see and utilize those drives on my ubuntu machine.  I have been able to connect to a shared folder using *smb://dads-tower/user/public*.  However, that is only a single directory and not the full drive. I have not been able to connect any of the shared directories on the other drives using the same format.  I don't see a way to specify the drive letter.  (Shame on you M$)

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Wes

Comment: It is not Windows there are no drive letters, only directories. Create an SMB link to each one.

Comment: Wow!  That will be over 250 directories if I need to gt to each drive.  I am new to lynux so I guess I will have to try using a batch setup to mount and unmount directories as needed

Comment: Idea rearrange your directories. Dir 1 and all the dir 1 subs under it etc. Then a link to dir one is all the subs under it. That is how my NAS is setup 5 dirs cover all the sub dirs.

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured this out; at least for me.  It appears that lynux does see the shared name of the drive in question.  So, once I tried using smb://server/shared name, I got connected.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Wes